# jQuery plugin raty.js within Backbone view keeps reloading same star images from server

Tags: jquery-plugins, backbone.js, raty

Whenever I hover over the wbotelhos/raty.js plugin on a page it will repeatedly fetch star-on.png and star-off.png from server as the stars go on and off. Is there a way to use a local client cache of the images? I'm testing in Chrome. I use the following Backbone.View render code to insert the plugin into an Item element.

```
render: function(manage) {
  this.collection.each(function(user) {
    this.insertView("ul", new User.Views.Item({
      model: user
    }));
  }, this);

  return manage(this).render().then(function(el) {
    // Only re-focus if invalid
    this.$("input.invalid").focus();
    this.$(".raty-test").raty();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to solve this i wrote github: charlesjshort / raty forked from wbotelhos/raty to replace the code for setting image source with a setSource function which sets images to object in  localStorage array. I use github: doomhz/jQuery-Image-Cache to preload the images into the localStorage array.